# SPI communication with MLX75306 optical sensor array

Tags: arduino, spi, interrupts

I am having some trouble talking to an optical sensor array with SPI (MLX75306, [data sheet](https://www.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx75306-datasheet-melexis.pdf)). I am using an Arduino Nano Every. I am not familiar with SPI communication and I have the feeling I am missing something essential in the communication protocol. I attached an interrupt to the Frameready pin of the optical array, but this interrupt never gets triggered. Why not?

From what I understand from the datasheet, sending the “Start Integration” command should result in Frameready going high after a set time. I have got my Arduino connected to the MLX75306 as follows:

```
Arduino —> MLX75306:

D12/MISO → MISO
D11/MOSI → MOSI
D13 → SCLK
D6 → Frameready
D5 → CS
+3V3 → pin 5 & 6 (3v3)
GND → pin 4 (GND)
```

with a 1 μF and 0.1 μF in parallel between pin 4 and pin 5 on the MLX75306.

This is the Arduino code (I am not doing a detailed read out of the sensor yet, this code is mainly to get the interrupt to trigger):

```
#include <SPI.h>

const int dataReadyPin = 6;
const int chipSelectPin = 5;
const byte MLX75306_CR = 0b11110000;   // chip reset
const byte MLX75306_SI = 0b10111000;   // start integration
const byte MLX75306_RO8 = 0b10011001; //Read 8bit
const byte MLX75306_SM = 0b11000110; // Sleep Mode
const byte MLX75306_WU = 0b11000011; // Wake UP
const byte TIME_INT_MSB = 0b01001110; // MSB+LSB is one 16 bit byte
const byte TIME_INT_LSB = 0b00100100; //current value 20000, for 10 ms integration time
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(dataReadyPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(chipSelectPin, OUTPUT);

  initiate();
  start();
  sleep();
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(dataReadyPin), ReadData, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  byte inByte = 0;
  initiate();
  start();
  acquire_8b();
  Serial.println("Sent");
  delay(2000);


}
void initiate()
{
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(MLX75306_CR);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}

void start()
{
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(MLX75306_WU);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}
void sleep()
{
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(MLX75306_SM);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}

void acquire_8b()
{
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(MLX75306_SI);
  SPI.transfer(TIME_INT_MSB);
  SPI.transfer(TIME_INT_LSB);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}

void ReadData()
{
  byte inByte;
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(MLX75306_RO8);
  SPI.transfer(0x02);
  SPI.transfer(0x8F);
  inByte = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  Serial.println(inByte, BIN);
}
```

Comment: Did you double-check the I/O voltages? The Arduino Nano seems to be a 5V part, meaning if you digitalWrite(pin, HIGH) that pin will go to 5V and potentially damage your sensor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the chip you use, but here are some quick suggestions:

- Try to validate that you can get *some* data out of the chip before even doing any complex command sequences. This is because SPI does not raise errors when something goes wrong. If there's no chip connected or the SPI settings are wrong the transactions will still run! The only indication of the problem will be that every byte you receive is 0x00. So, it's good to start with the simplest code that would get your device to send a non-zero byte.
- After a quick read through the datasheet, a good candidate for sanity checking your SPI coms is the... "sanity byte" that this specific device sends in reply to commands. I suggest you write code to read and validate it.
- Double-check the timing requirements, for instance how much time you must wait after CS goes low before sending data, or how much time you must wait after a reset to send the first command, etc. If it's a very small value (eg. 50 ns) you do not usually have to insert a delay command in the Arduino code. If it's micro/milliseconds, you might have to.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work reasonably based on your suggestions. The sanity Byte by was the key to checking whether the MLX75306 understood my commands as it includes a valid command counter. I also found that the integration time I was using was too high, causing the chip to time out in its response. I still do not have a working interrupt, but I am able to read the data from the chip without having to wait for "Frameready".
I am using the following code now:

```
#include <SPI.h>

const int dataReadyPin = 6;
const int chipSelectPin = 5;
const byte MLX75306_CR = 0b11110000;   // chip reset
const byte MLX75306_SI = 0b10111000;   // start integration
const byte MLX75306_RO8 = 0b10011001; //Read 8bit
const byte MLX75306_SM = 0b11000110; // Sleep Mode
const byte MLX75306_WU = 0b11000011; // Wake UP
const byte TIME_INT_MSB = 0b00000000; // MSB+LSB is one 16 bit byte
const byte TIME_INT_LSB = 0b00010100; //current value 20 clock-cycles of integration time


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:


  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(dataReadyPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(chipSelectPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  initiate();

  //attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(dataReadyPin), ReadData, RISING);
}

void loop() {
 
  byte inByte[140] ;
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);

  inByte[0] = SPI.transfer(MLX75306_SI);
  inByte[1] = SPI.transfer(TIME_INT_MSB);
  inByte[2] = SPI.transfer(TIME_INT_LSB);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  inByte[0] = SPI.transfer(0b10011001);
  inByte[1] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
  inByte[2] = SPI.transfer(0x91);
  for (int i = 0; i < 140; i++)
  {
    inByte[i] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
    if (i > 9 ) {
      Serial.print(inByte[i]);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
  }
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  Serial.println();
  delay(20);


}
void initiate()
{
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(2000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(MLX75306_CR);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  digitalWrite (chipSelectPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Good news. Did you see my above comment regarding I/O voltages? It looks like you're connecting a 3.3V sensor to a 5V microcontroller, which could (a) damage the sensor and (b) cause the missed interrupt, because logic high for the ATmega4809 running at 5V is 3.5V, above the level that the sensor can possibly drive the pin.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good point too. I've been working mostly with teensy lately, so when I used an old arduino for this project I had forgotten they work at a different logic level. I'll change it out for a teensy, and report back if that makes the frameready trigger work.

Comment: With a Teensy the interrupt works, thanks!

Comment: Awesome. I also mostly work with Teensy and haven't looked back to ATmega boards!